# Is it possible to query a mapping in solidity in reverse order?

Tags: solidity

Let's say I have following mapping:

```
mapping(uint => mapping(string => address))
```

So it's easy to get `address` if I know `uint` and `string` (for a specific entry).

But is it possible to get `uint` if I know `address` and `string`? Or is there a different data structure in solidity for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do that in solidity. Solidity actually doesn't store the `key` data, only its `keccak256` hash is used.

The Solidity type mapping is a storage-only key-value data structure that does not keep track of the keys that were assigned a non-zero value.

You can't even iterate over the mappings if you don't know all the keys. Mappings also don't have the concept of length. Mappings are not exactly similar to Hash Tables.

You can read more about the Mapping [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#mapping-types)

Comment: Thanks, that was very explanatory.